# TypeError: e is undefined in d3.min.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a following function so that I can use the zoom in function in the map of India.but the error e is undefined in d3.min.js is coming on line 3:12958

```
d3.json("india.geojson",function(error,data){
        var data = d3.range(2000).map(function() {
                return [randomX(),randomY()];
        });

        var canvas = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width",750)
                        .attr("height",750)
                        .append("g")
                        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
                        .append("g");

        var color = d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([1,50])
                        .range(["red","blue"]);

        var group = canvas.selectAll("g")
                        .data(data.features)
                        .enter()
                        .append("g");

        var projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(1000).translate([-1000,700]);

        var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

        var areas = group.append("path")
                                .attr("d",path)
                                .attr("class","area")
                                .attr("fill",function(d){return color(d.properties.ID_1); });

        function zoom() {
                       group.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
            }

             group.append("text")
                        .attr("x",function(d){ return path.centroid(d)[0];})
                        .attr("y",function(d){ return path.centroid(d)[1];})
                        .attr("text-anchor","middle")
                        .text(function(d){ return d.properties.NAME_1 ;});

});
```

Comment: I suggest you use the non-minified version of d3.js to figure out which code really goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `zoom` function outside your `d3.json` function, or at least above the reference you give to the zoom function. At the moment you reference it `zoom` is undefined and it is probably what causes your problem.

Comment: Ok but you need to be a bit more specific, use nob minified js, tell us on what line in your code the error happens and or give a jsfiddle so we can check.

Comment: I dont know the lie number as the error which appear on the console is:       TypeError: e is undefined in d3.min.js at line number 3 and column 12958